# Webpack in NextSJ Config - ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character

Tags: webpack, next.js

I getting error while building from nextjs app or starting server with yarn dev command.
This is next.config.js. it was work correctly until i install and uninstall next-less plugin.
I reverting code to previous state but error is not resolved.

```js
const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    HOST_URL: process.env.HOST_URL,
    BUILD_ENV: process.env.BUILD_ENV,
  },
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (isServer) {
      const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style\/css.*?/;
      const origExternals = [...config.externals];
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      config.externals = [
        // eslint-disable-line
        (context, request, callback) => {
          // eslint-disable-line
          if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback();
          if (typeof origExternals[0] === 'function') {
            origExternals[0](context, request, callback);
          } else {
            callback();
          }
          return null;
        },
        ...(typeof origExternals[0] === 'function' ? [] : origExternals),
      ];

      config.module.rules.unshift({
        test: antStyles,
        use: 'null-loader',
      });
    }
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [withBundleAnalyzer, {}],
    [withImages],
    [withCss],
    [
      withSass,
      {
        cssModules: true,
        cssLoaderOptions: {
          localIdentName: '[path]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  nextConfig,
);
```

Comment: do you have any `.less` files in the project?

Comment: no. this error shown for scss files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I deleted yarn.lock file in my root directory of project so when yarn installed node package, some independent version of  dependency installed too.
this cause scss loader didn't installed correctly and webpack raising error.